# Too many redirect when trying to access "File CV" page on SO Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I try to access "File CV" (http://careers.stackoverflow.com/billing/jobseekers) on StackOverflow Careers, it results in a too many redirect error.

Here's [my profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/loicwolff).

Maybe it has to do with the fact that I'm register as student?

Edit: same goes when I try to access "upgrade account" (http://careers.stackoverflow.com/billing/jobseekers/renew)

Comment: Confirmed (Chrome 5.0.342.9 beta, Mac OS X 10.6.3)

Comment: Confirmed (Chrome 4.1.249.1064, Vista SP2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a configuration error in the NY datacenter.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: This same problem is happening to me when trying to "Create a Profile"  on Careers. It seems to be redirecting infinitely between http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one and http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv
It's been happening since yesterday in Chrome and FF 3.6 (I haven't checked other browsers).

Comment: To reproduce the problems, click on "create a profile" from this page: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @JohnnyO I can reproduce your error, but it is not related to this particular question (the "File CV" page no longer exists).  Could you open a separate bug report?

Comment: Hi David, I opened this bug report per your request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104779/too-many-redirects-when-trying-to-create-a-profile-on-so-careers