# Too many redirects when trying to "create a profile" on SO Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When clicking on "create a profile" on this page:
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

I get a "too many redirects" error.

It seems that the browser is redirecting infinitely between careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one and careers.stackoverflow.com/cv

Comment: We're looking into this...

Comment: @matt-sherman this bug seems to have persisted. I'm getting the same error on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one when clicking on "Try Stack Overflow".

Answer (score 1):

At some point this was fixed.  Just doing a little housecleaning.